# Insert unique values to generic list

Tags: c#

I am using a generic list which is getting duplicated with the values. I just want to add distinct values into the list. Below is the code I am using. Can anybody help me how to avoid duplicates into the list

```
foreach (Questionnaire_Response questionnaireResponse in Questionnaire_Response.FindWithQuery(query))
{
    if (questionnaireResponse.Response_Descr == response)
    {
        submitOrderResponseItems.RESP_KEY = questionnaireResponse.Response_Id;
        submitOrderResponseItems.DESCR = questionnaireResponse.Response_Descr;
        submitOrderResponseItems.UPDATED_DATE = currentDate;
        submitOrderResponseItems.UPDATED_TIME = currentDateTime;
        submitOrderResponse.Add(submitOrderResponseItems);
    }                                   
}
```

Comment: before to add check on exist... List.Contains(val)

Comment: Hi Antony. I checked before adding . but , it will take the current value and duplicates with existing values. For example if there are 2 existing values in the list means, in the next iteration it will duplicates existing 2 and current value to the same. So all 3 items will show the same values

Answer (score 7):

Use a `HashSet<T>` instead and a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>` if needed.

Comment: +1 - A [SortedSet<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd412070.aspx) can be used if order is important.

Comment: Smile at your own "+1", :)

Comment: @David It was for the answer...honestly... :D

Comment: I said "smile", not "laugh", :)

Comment: With no further explanation, I don't think it helps the OP very much.

Comment: @Scorpi0, I think Daniel's answer is proper in details. Given such clue, it is not hard to get the rest. StackOverflow is not the best place to find the "exact" solution, and idea is more important.